# Ajax promise rejected, no request sent

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My whole API is working fine, but one of my api endpoints is not being accessed at all. I have the following wrapper for the `RESTAdapter` (I use this mainly for logging purposes), which is working fine for most endpoints:

```
SettingsApp.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    bulkCommit: false,
    namespace: 'api',
    url: SettingsApp.APIUrlFinder(),
    serializer: SettingsApp.MetaRESTSerializer.create(),
    ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
        var ajaxPromise = this._super(url, type, hash);
        console.log('Adapter.ajax > %o > url=%s hash=%o ajaxPromise=%o', type, url, hash, ajaxPromise);
        ajaxPromise.then(function(json){
            console.log('Adapter.ajax.ajaxPromise.then -> %o', json);
        });
        return ajaxPromise;
    }
});
```

Now when accessing one of the endpoints, `ajaxPromise.isRejected` is `true` and the ajax request is not even sent to the backend (neither request nor reply can be seen on the `network` tab on chrome devtools) I assume that since `isRejected` is true, the request is not sent.

Why could `isRejected` be set? My models / controllers / routes are properly configured.